# Django 1.5 multiple user authentication or

Tags: python, django

I created a Django 1.5 WebApp with custom `User` model. And it works. :)

I already had a second `User2` model that another App was using. This second `User2` model isn't a Django app so it was built with different criteria. And it is already in production with many users.

Now I have the need to give both `User` and `User2` the possibility to log-in and do completely different things.

I'm thinking about one single Django App to manage everything because in both cases I need to use both models: when `User` is logged-in I need also some information about `User2` and viceversa.

I don't see a way to merge `User`, `User2` because they have completely different fields. Plus `User2` has a `ForeignKey` that points to `User`.

After several trials I discovered that django supports only one `AUTH_USER_MODEL`.
So now I don't know how to proceed.

I see the following alternatives:

- create an abstract User Model (`AbstractUser`) and then subclass `User` and `User2` but I do not know how and if this will work
- create a completely new Django WebApp but this require a bigger (and maybe unnecessary) effort
- find another way to authenticate `User2`, maybe writing my custom auth code

Do you see any other option? Which is the best?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand exactly your problem but if I did I think what you're looking for is a `OneToOneField`.

When I'm working on projects where the clients want customized users, one of the best solution is to create a new model with a `OneToOneField` pointing to the Django User like a `Profile` model. When you have an `User` object, you can do `user.profile` and you get the profile related with user (so you can do `user.profile.any_profile_field`).

It goes also in the other way, if you have the object `Profile` you can access to the `User` object like `profile.user` and do also `profile.user.first_name`

So if it fits well with your issue as I think, you should change your model to be a `OneToOneField` to `User` like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    field1 = models.CharField....
    #     ...    ...     ...
    #      Your fields here
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! I ended up creating a new Django WebApp